# Handling click events inside ABPersonViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, abpersonviewcontroller

I am implementing

```
- (BOOL)personViewController:(ABPersonViewController *)personViewController shouldPerformDefaultActionForPerson:(ABRecordRef)person property:(ABPropertyID)property identifier:(ABMultiValueIdentifier)identifier
```

delegate in my custom class which subclasses `ABPersonViewController`. The delegate method is catching the click events inside the `ABPersonViewController` subclass. But how will I know which field exactly has been clicked. For eg. if I click on the home address field, how will I handle this case inside the delegate method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
- (BOOL)personViewController:(ABPersonViewController *)personViewController shouldPerformDefaultActionForPerson:(ABRecordRef)person property:(ABPropertyID)property identifier:(ABMultiValueIdentifier)identifier{
if(property == kABPersonAddressProperty){
    ABMutableMultiValueRef multi = ABRecordCopyValue(person, property);
    CFStringRef address = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(multi, identifier);
    NSLog(@"Address %@", (NSString *)address);
    // Do your tasks here
    CFRelease(address);
}
return YES;
}
```

Just like `kABPersonAddressProperty` you can check all other properties like phone number, email, url etc.